Archeological, geological and astronomical correlations to the flood of Noah
In reviewing tractate Rosh HaShanah 12a in connection with the rules regarding determining halacha between Rabbi Yehosuah and Rabbi Eliezer, I stumbled across an interesting detail concerning them.
It states that concerning the age of the world and the flood, the Sages follow the opinion of Rabbi Eliezer.
And this caused me to look more carefully at what Rabbi Eliezer actually is quoted as saying there.

דְּתַנְיָא: ״בִּשְׁנַת שֵׁשׁ מֵאוֹת שָׁנָה לְחַיֵּי נֹחַ בַּחֹדֶשׁ הַשֵּׁנִי בְּשִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר יוֹם לַחֹדֶשׁ״, רַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ אוֹמֵר: אוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם שִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר בְּאִיָּיר הָיָה, יוֹם שֶׁמַּזַּל כִּימָה שׁוֹקֵעַ בַּיּוֹם וּמַעְיָנוֹת מִתְמַעֲטִין. וּמִתּוֹךְ שֶׁשִּׁינּוּ מַעֲשֵׂיהֶן, שִׁינָּה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עֲלֵיהֶם מַעֲשֵׂה בְרֵאשִׁית, וְהֶעֱלָה מַזַּל כִּימָה בַּיּוֹם, וְנָטַל שְׁנֵי כּוֹכָבִים מִכִּימָה וְהֵבִיא מַבּוּל לָעוֹלָם. רַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר אוֹמֵר: אוֹתוֹ הַיּוֹם שִׁבְעָה עָשָׂר בְּמַרְחֶשְׁוָן הָיָה, יוֹם שֶׁמַּזַּל כִּימָה עוֹלֶה בַּיּוֹם וּמַעְיָנוֹת מִתְגַּבְּרִים.
י״ב א
וּמִתּוֹךְ שֶׁשִּׁינּוּ מַעֲשֵׂיהֶם, שִׁינָּה הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא עֲלֵיהֶם מַעֲשֵׂה בְרֵאשִׁית, וְהֶעֱלָה מַזַּל כִּימָה בַּיּוֹם, וְנָטַל שְׁנֵי כּוֹכָבִים וְהֵבִיא מַבּוּל לָעוֹלָם. בִּשְׁלָמָא לְרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ, הַיְינוּ דִּכְתִיב: ״שֵׁנִי״. אֶלָּא לְרַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר, מַאי ״שֵׁנִי״? שֵׁנִי לְדִין. בִּשְׁלָמָא לְרַבִּי יְהוֹשֻׁעַ, הַיְינוּ דְּשִׁינָּה. אֶלָּא לְרַבִּי אֱלִיעֶזֶר, מַאי שִׁינָּה? כִּדְרַב חִסְדָּא. דְּאָמַר רַב חִסְדָּא: בְּרוֹתְחִין קִלְקְלוּ וּבְרוֹתְחִין נִידּוֹנוּ. בְּרוֹתְחִין קִלְקְלוּ — בַּעֲבֵירָה, וּבְרוֹתְחִין נִידּוֹנוּ

It mentions that G-d altered the works of Creation and caused the constellation, Kima (This is the constellation called Draco today.) to ascend and G-d grasped two stars (from that constellation) and brought a flood to the world. Rabbi Eliezer explains that this was actually in the month of MarCheshvan after Tishrei (when G-d judges the entire world) and Rav Chisda, explaining the view of Rabbi Eliezer says that initially the waters from the flood were scalding hot. This suggests volcanic involvement, at least initially, like pyroclastic flows.
Classic dating for this event attempts to count onward from the exile of Adam and Chava from Gan Eden and places the flood in the year 1656, 4,128 years ago like is found in Seder HaDorot.
But archeologically and geologically, there is no obvious evidence for such a cataclysmic event in that time frame where all life (or even a vast majority of life) was wiped from the earth.
But the details from Rabbi Eliezer point to something else entirely. Rabbi Eliezer is describing a very large celestial cycle connected to the shifting of Earth's pole star.
He is saying that when the binary star in the constellation of Draco (Kima) was ascending (meaning becoming Earth's pole star), in the month of MarCheshvan, the flood began. The Draco constellation actually has about 8 different binary stars contained within it's pattern and not all of them align with the pole star pathway for Earth's view.
That because the polar axis of the Earth wobbles slightly, the pole star changes over time to align with various stars in the sky, in different constellations. This pattern of alignment can be charted out and anticipated with precision. One of the pole stars in that alignment is a binary star, called Thuban, in the constellation of Draco. This binary star becomes the pole star for Earth every 26,000 years.
The last time Thuban was the pole star for Earth was from about 3942 BCE to 1793 BCE which was when the pyramids were being built in Egypt. That does not agree with the traditional time of the flood details like found in Seder HaDorot.
But in the cycle prior to the last one, which was approximately 30,000 BCE, it coincides with a very significant geological event. It overlaps a period called The Last Glacial Maximum.
In the Last Glacial Maximum, much of the earth was covered with ice sheets,temperatures dropped significantly, desertification spread over large parts of the world creating dust bowls making agriculture extremely difficult  and sea levels dropped by almost 400 feet! Many of the details described in the Torah about the Earth not yielding up its produce willingly match these conditions like is mentioned in Bereshit 3:17-19. With sea levels dropping so precipitously, human settlements followed the waterlines to lowlands.
There is archeological evidence  of such things like significant human settlement and even cities under the ocean off the coast of India and elsewhere. Similarly, the remains from places like Gobekli Tepe and Karahan Tepe in Turkey extend back to these time frames.
Following the Last Glacial Maximum, this process reversed itself, sometimes rapidly. Areas of human settlement could have been inundated and, in fact there is evidence of such things around the Black Sea in the vicinity of Mount Ararat.
Are there any traditional Torah sources which suggest, the flood story of Noach is actually an older human memory from this time period indicated by Rabbi Eliezer?

Isn't כימה Pleiades?

One can debate the archeological dating of the Flood or the Ice Age. For instance, the well known fossil record with mixtures of different life forms in certain highly debatable order across the world can be viewed as the result of the flood. One can also view the ice age as help of G-d so that humans after the flood spread all over the world.

@Harel13 According to Jastrow, he says no. It wouldn't be a surprise either in the context of the connection with Egypt. The pyramids align  on the north side specifically to Thurban from Draco. It may be associated with what they viewed as their Heavenly influence. In that context, see also Yishayahu 27:1 and the commentaries of Rashi and Radak.

@YaacovDeane many disagree with Jastrow. See for example this summary, coupled with an explanation of your gemara per the understanding that כימה is Pleiades: https://asif.co.il/wpfb-file/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%94/.

"The last time Thuban was the pole star for Earth was from about 3942 BCE to 1793 BCE which was when the pyramids were being built in Egypt. That does not agree with the traditional time of the flood details like found in Seder HaDorot."
This page (https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3915966/jewish/Timeline-of-Jewish-History.htm) lists the flood as occurring in -2105 BCE, which is between those two dates

@user9806 Thanks for pointing out my typo. I corrected it. It doesn’t change the main idea. The detail of the flood is that all life, or a large percentage of it was wiped from the earth. That wasn’t happening when the pyramids were being built or even 2 centuries before.

@Harel13 I understand that some believe the Pleiades (the Seven Sisters) is Kima. But the stars of the Pleiades don’t serve as the Pole star to Earth. It’s significant in other ways and to various ancient cultures. But being the Pole star isn’t one of them. And that cycle of the Pole star is essential.

My point is that you believe that the pole star is relevant here simply because you identify כימה with Draco, but it's not at all clear that that is the correct identification, hence the pole star may not at all be relevant to understanding this gemara. Again, I recommend at least checking out what the above linked essay has to say on the astronomy of that gemara with regards to a Pleiades identification.

If you're going to stick with the Draco identification, I recommend at least explaining why you think that identification is preferable to all of the others (there are others besides Pleiades, although Pleiades is IMO the most well-known one).

@Harel13 I am not saying the usage of כימה is only Draco. It is possible that this term is used differently by individuals. My attention on Draco is because Rabbi Eliezer appears to be identifying a binary star (the 2 stars grasped). That connects it to the pole star cycle.  כימה may also be associated with the concepts of Leviathan and the Tanin. (See Isaiah 27:1 and also Bereshit 1:21). From Isaiah, that would suggest 3 possible constellations associated with this term. Interesting linked article BTW.

@Harel13 I seem to recall Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan talking about a particular commentary on Mishnah from the 19th century that explored this subject. The Rav was prominent, but once published, the Orthodox community at the time ostracized him. Kaplan commented that there were efforts to censor his writings even physically tearing published works out of texts of Mishnah.

@YaacovDeane did you mean to tag me? I don't have a problem with the question, I simply think that it's based on a mistaken premise, but I suppose that it's relevant for whoever agrees with Jastrow.

@Harel13 Yes, I intended it. I wasn't thinking you had issues with the question. I thought perhaps you might be familiar with the Mishnah commentary I mentioned in connection from Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan.

Ah. No, unfortunately I don't know who you're thinking about.

@YaacovDeane are you referring to the Drush Ohr Hachayim commenteary by R. Yisrael Lifshitz?

Two stars is not a binary star. Two stars means two of the stars visible from Earth. Whether or not that Gemara is literal is a broader question.

@N.T. You are correct that "two stars" can mean any two stars within the specified constellation. But that would beg the question, which two random & unrelated stars within the given constellation are significant and why does this relate to Earth in any way? But in context, for that constellation and that particular, pulsating binary star in that constellation, there is a relationship & significance to Earth because it also turns out to also be the pole star for Earth on a regular 26,000 year cycle. Something observable to the naked eye from a night sky.
